# d3.js sunburst with dynamically built updatable data structure

Tags: d3.js, dynamic, graph

I am attempting to create a fully dynamic Sunburst graph using d3.js.
The examples and tutorials I have located tend to use existing/fully-populated data structures which may have the ability to modify the value of existing arcs but does not allow the ability to add child arcs as needed.

Likewise the tutorials I have located which allow new datasets simply replace the existing structure and begin drawing from scratch.
This is not the behavior I am trying to implement.

What I need is a dynamically built graph based on incoming data as it is provided.

I am able to append children to the end of the data set, transition and render the results without issue. The problem occurs any time I insert a child somewhere within the existing structure, d3’s selectAll() does not function as expected. It includes the new arc (which has yet to be drawn) resulting in any remaining arcs being rendered incorrectly. Then when transitioning the arcs it seems to get the arcs Dom ID and data it supposedly represents gets mixed up. The new arc is not visible and an empty space exists where new arc should be placed.

**To be clear my intent is:**

1. Add to the existing data structure allowing new children to be added when new information is provided
2. To transition existing arcs opening space for the new arcs before they are created and drawn

**Broken down into four steps of the jsfiddle example:**

1. Initialization of the graph (draws an invisible “root” arc)

   { name:"a_0", children: [] }
2. Adding First Child data and it’s children to root

   { name:"a_0", children:[ 
       { name:"a_1", children:[ { name:"a_2", children:[ { name:"a_3" } ] } ] } 
   ] }
3. Adding Second Child and underlying children to root

   { name:"a_0", children:[
       { name:"a_1", children:[ { name:"a_2", children:[ { name:"a_3" } ] } ] },
       { name:"a_4", children:[ { name:"a_5", children:[ { name:"a_6" } ] } ] } 
   ] }
4. Inserting another child within the existing arc a_2

   { name:"a_0", children:[
       { name:"a_1", children:[ 
           { name:"a_2", children:[ 
               { name:"a_3" },
                   { name:"a_7" }
               ] }
           ] },
       { name:"a_4", children:[ 
           { name:"a_5", children:[ 
               { name:"a_6" } 
           ] } 
       ] } 
   ] }

**Step 1** works just fine

**Step 2** draws the arcs properly

**Step 3** transitions the existing arcs and adds the new arcs to the graph

**Step 4** results some unexpected behavior.

During the transition of existing and entering of new arcs some of the arcs "jump around" losing the proper association with their respective data
The end result appears to be:

- a_0 - is correct
- a_1 & a_2 - look correct
- a_3 - has shrunk to accommodate the new sibling a_7 - expected behavior
- a_4 - disappears
- a_5 - jumps down where a_4 should be
- a_6 - (looks like) it is duplicated and exists once where it should be and where a_5 should be
- a_7 - not displayed, location where it should be is empty space and appears to be associated with a_6 data

What the end result looks like and what is really going on are not the same.

- In the attempt to update the graph the selectAll() for the existing arcs includes (a_0, a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4, a_5, a_7). Where the existing a_6 is not included in the selectAll() but a_7 (which has not been drawn) is.
- The enter() function appears to operate on the existing a_6 which is then treated as a new arc

It looked like I was on the right track getting all the way to a_6, but I have not figured out the reason for the behavior when adding a_7.

**The jsFidde executes the steps as described above including:**

- Unique colors for each arc
- A table displaying the name of each arc,
- If the arc is being handled by d3js' selectAll() (i.e. "existing") or enter() (i.e. "new"),
- The d3 Index as it is currently being assigned when drawing existing or new arcs.
- Expected target position where each arc should appear after any transitioning,
- Arctween information as an Arc is being transitioned from its former location to the new location and

**Questions:**

- What is going on that would cause this behavior in Step 4?
- Is there a way to ensure the integrity between each arc and the data it represents?
- Is there a way to insert children into the existing structure or update the graph in this dynamic manor?

Working example on jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/mfitzgerald/j2eowwya/

```
var dataObj = { name:"a_0", color: "none" };
var height = 300;
var width = 500;
var radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;
var graph = d3.select("#graph")
    .attr('height', height)
    .attr('width', width)
    .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

var partition = d3.layout.partition()
            .sort(null)
            .size([2 * Math.PI, radius * radius])
            .value(function(d, i) { return 1; });
var arc = d3.svg.arc()
    .startAngle(function(d)  { if (isNaN(d.x))  { d.x = 0; }  d.x0 = d.x;   return d.x; })
    .endAngle(function(d)    { if (isNaN(d.dx)) { d.dx = 0; } d.dx0 = d.dx; return d.x + d.dx; })
    .innerRadius(function(d) { if (isNaN(d.y))  { d.y = 0; }  d.y0 = d.y;   return Math.sqrt(d.y); })
    .outerRadius(function(d) { if (isNaN(d.dy)) { d.dy = 0; } d.dy0 = d.dy; return Math.sqrt(d.y + d.dy); });

var arcTween = function(a) {
    var i = d3.interpolate({x: a.x0, dx: a.dx0, y: a.y0, dy: a.dy0}, a);
    return function(t) {
        var b = i(t);
        a.x0 = b.x;
        a.dx0 = b.dx;
        a.y0 = b.y;
        a.dy0 = b.dy;
        displayStats("arctween", b);
        return arc(b);
    };
}

// Root Arc
graph.datum(dataObj).selectAll('path.arc')
    .data(partition.nodes)
    .enter()
    .append('path')
        .attr('class', function(d) { return "arc " + d.name; })
        .attr("d", arc)
        .attr("id", function(d, i) { return "path_"+i; })
        .attr("name", function(d) { return d.name; })
        .style("fill", "none");


function updateGraph() {
    console.log("Update Graph");
    console.log(dataObj);

    var update = graph.datum(dataObj).selectAll('path.arc')
                .data(partition.nodes);

    // Move existing Arcs
    update.each(function(d, i) {
            displayStats("target", d, i, "existing");
            var domId = $(this).attr("id");
            console.log("["+i+"] Exist Arc name:"+d.name+", dom_id:"+domId);
        })
        .transition()
            .delay(function(d, i) { return i * 250; })
            .duration(1500)
            .attrTween("d", arcTween);

    // Add New Arcs
    update.enter().append('path')
        .attr('class', function(d, i) { return "arc "+d.name; })
        .attr("d", arc)
        .attr("id", function(d, i) {
            var domId = "path_"+i;
            console.log("["+i+"] NEW Arc name:"+d.name+", dom_id:"+domId);
            displayStats("target", d, i, "new");
            return domId;
        })
        .style("stroke", "#fff")
        .style("fill", function(d) { return d.color; })
        .style("opacity", 0)
        .transition()
            .delay(function(d, i) { return i * 250; })
            .duration(1500)
            .style("opacity", .5)
            .attrTween("d", arcTween);
}
```

Comment: Looks like you may need to [use a key function](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/constancy/) when joining your data with `.data()`, so that old data gets bound to old objects and new data gets bound to new objects, rather than just binding by the index in the array.

Comment: That did the trick! I have forked the jsfiddle with the fix [here](https://jsfiddle.net/mfitzgerald/qvwcc4cf/). Transitions will need to be altered. But the big issue has been addressed! Thank you for the assist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Gordon has answered the question. The issue was resolved by adding a [key function](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/constancy/) when joining with .data() in the updateGraph code.

Forked example on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mfitzgerald/qvwcc4cf/)

```
var update = graph.datum(dataObj).selectAll('path.arc')
            .data(partition.nodes, function(d) { return d.name; } );
```

I believe the answers to the questions are:

- The .data() function uses an indexed array which only uniquely identifies each arc given any new arcs are appended to the end of the array. Once one is inserted this would cause the data, graphed arcs and associated DOM ids to be misaligned.
- Using the key function, as suggested by Gordon, allows unique identification of specific nodes keeping the Data and Graph in sync as expected.

***Update***

An additional modification would need to be made as the DOM id was set by the array index of the data element there would still be an invalid association with the DOM and the underlying graph/data.

This would result in 2 a_4 DOM id's. Instead of using the array index using the Node Name as the DOM id should keep this association correct.